# Pass method from parent component to child component in vuejs

Tags: methods, vue.js

Can someone help me with passing a method from a parent to a child component in vue.js? I've been trying to do it by passing the method in as a prop...

My parent component snippet:

```
methods: { 

    test: function () {
        console.log('from test method')
    }

}

<template>
    <child-component test="test"><child-component>
</template>
```

Child component snippet

```
created: {
    this.test() //returns test is not a function
},

props: ['test']
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://michaelnthiessen.com/pass-function-as-prop/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are trying to pass a function as literal as described [here](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Literal-vs-Dynamic). You end up with `test` prop being String... You should use `:` to indicate dynamic binding as follows:

`<child-component :test="test"><child-component>"`

Comment: Confirmed working, even though you may want to consider mixins.

Comment: Yeah, totally. I mean if you only pass it to achieve code reuse then go with mixins.

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve: If you want to use just one variant of the injected function, a mixin might solve your problem as well, but if you want to use different variants depending on the parent a mixin will not work. Interestingly, if the prop value is a function, it is passed to the client, whereas if the prop value is an object containing a field with a function, the respective field is stripped from the prop value that goes into the child component (which is a clone of the original value).