# Vue.js passing a method from parent to child

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and trying to figure out what the correct way of passing methods from a parent to a child component.

Using v-bind:"function-name" works fine ans is the suggested answer here - [Pass method from parent component to child component in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240291/pass-method-from-parent-component-to-child-component-in-vuejs)

but it seems that using an event emitter is the more commonly used solution (see https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-communication/ for reference)

Is there's an advantage for one option over the other?

Comment: Using event emitters is very rarely the elegant solution with Vue, use props for passing down data to direct children, use Vuex for more or less everything else.

Comment: Personally, I despise the overuse of Vuex, in much the same way Redux is overused in React. Props down, events up is the standard. Passing a method is rarely necessary, but sometimes useful. I guess the pertinent question here is, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Bert The problem with events is that they're just a renamed PubSub: you're throwing unscoped and untyped data into the void. It simply doesn't scale.

Comment: @Nit I don't disagree with you when you're looking at a large scale project, but the vast number of people asking questions here are looking at a handful of components in their apps. Vuex is a premature optimization in these cases. IMHO and YMMV of course.

Comment: It obviously depends on your use case (which is not detailed), but another option might be [scoped slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots)

Comment: I'm working on a small comparison between React / Angular and Vue.js while in React you pass in a method and in Angular you use event emitters (@output) Vue seems to support / suggest the use of either - I'm just trying to figure if there's a preference here.