# Define generic component methods from the view VUE

Tags: vue.js, methods, view, components

I have a simple component with a button, which is implemented in the view.
I would like that depend of the views, this button (which is in the component) works different 
How to define the method in the view, not in the component?

Comment: Can you add any code example?

Comment: It was solver here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240291/pass-method-from-parent-component-to-child-component-in-vuejs But thanks!